# Dynamic SQL to pass table name and return Max ID value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

Here is what I am trying to do I have list of tables(50 of them) and in all the tables I have one common column called "ID", what I want to do is pass table name that will dynamically return my MAX(ID) value. i need the MAX(ID) value since I will be using this value for other stuff.

So I was thinking of creating a function where I will pass table name and it will return me MAX(ID) value and then I can use that function in my other select statements.But the problem here is SQL functions does not support dynamic SQL

Any suggestion on what other options do I have, remember I need the max(id) value in a SQL.

Comment: Why can't you use a stored procedure?

Answer (score 4):

```
create function [dbo].[LastIdOf](@TableName varchar(50)) returns int
as
begin
   declare @LastId int;
   select @LastId = convert(int, i.last_value) from sys.tables t inner join sys.identity_columns i on t.object_id = i.object_id where t.name = @TableName;
   return @LastId;
end
```

Comment: interesting solution based on the identity column, tnx. In this case, it is also possible to use the function

Comment: max value is not last value, what happens when somebody inserts with IDENTITY_INSERT OFF ?

Comment: Identity_insert off is usually used when someone is doing bulk loads.  The developer would have to consider whether this function would be in use at the same time tables were being bulk loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create a View and do a MAX(ID) on that?

Comment: Views can not accept parameter. I was thinking of creating a dynamic SP , and passing the table name to that SP , storing the value of SP in a #temp table and then using that value in my other SQL statements.

Answer (score 0):

```
create proc procTableMaxID (@Tablename varchar(100)
as
DECLARE @SQL AS nvarchar(500)

SET @SQL = 'SELECT Max(ID) from ' + @Tablename


EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL
```

Procs don't offer the flexibility to be used as a table or in a select statement, but there are ways around that.

Comment: Jeff , Thanks for your feedback , but I need to use the value from SP or function in SQL. Based on your SP I can store the value return my SP in temp table and I can use that temp table in my SELECT statement.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
select *
from TABLE A
where id = (
  select max(id)
  from TABLE
  where Table.key = A.Table.key
);
```

Comment: if it is a date field, then you will have to do like date <= currentdate or sysdate. Also, all key fields must be matched.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
'select max('+z.COLUMN_NAME +')' +' from '+z.TABLE_NAME  from (
SELECT u.TABLE_NAME,u.COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE u
left join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t on u.TABLE_NAME = t.TABLE_NAME
WHERE OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA + '.' + QUOTENAME(CONSTRAINT_NAME)), 'IsPrimaryKey') = 1
AND u.TABLE_NAME = t.TABLE_NAME) as z
```